# Reading array diagonally for transposition cipher?

Tags: php, cryptography

What I'm doing here is probably stupid and useless, but it turned out to be a great way to learn php, I appreciate your help.

I came up with a cipher which wraps text in a spiral much like Ulam's spiral maps numbers.

Refer to this image:

[image]

I consider the whole spiral as a cube, so if the string is too short to form a full cube, the remaining characters are left as empty spaces (in my picture example there is one space left, because the string is 24 characters and the next full cube is at 25 characters.

I want to add a further step of obfuscation, reading the array diagonally, so the output would be like this:

[image]

What is an easy/efficient way to achieve this? I'm storing the data in a 2D array, so it looks like this:

```
field[0][0]='l';
```

Bonus tangent question: How easily would something like this be deciphered?
Thank you!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You would need two loops (nested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the schema for a 5x5 square:

```
                                                yx yx yx yx yx

                       0 1 2 3 4            a > 00
                    0  a b c d e            b > 10 01
                    1  b c d e f            c > 20 11 02
                    2  c d e f g            d > 30 21 12 03
                    3  d e f g h            e > 40 31 22 13 04
                    4  e f g h i            f > 41 32 23 14
                                            g > 42 33 24
                                            h > 43 34
                                            i > 44
```

As you can see, we have:

- 9 groups (= cols+rows-1 or keys+keys+1);
- in each line, the y+x sum is the same, increasing from 0 to 8;
- in each line, the y decreases, while the x increases.
- each line ends when x reaches initial y

Based on these assumptions, we can write a single loop, using `$sum` and `$startY` as criteria to change line: when the decreasing `$x` has same value of `$startY`, we increment `$sum` and we set next `$startY` to the lowest value between `$sum` and the higher `$array` key, then we set next `$x` to the difference between `$sum` and `$y`:

```
$sum = $startY = $y = $x = 0;
while( $sum < 2*count($array)-1 )
{
    echo $array[$y][$x];

    if( $x == $startY )
    {
        $sum++;
        $startY = $y = min( $sum, count($array)-1 );
        $x = $sum - $y;
    }
    else
    {
        $y--;
        $x++;
    }
}
```

The result for above square is:

```
abbcccddddeeeeeffffggghhi
```

Looking at this <kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/544067)**</kbd> you can see three different examples.

Answer (score 1):

Just use for loops. It doesn't matter what language you are learning, you need to learn how to use for loops (or while loops or foreach loops or any good control structure).

You are going 00, then 10, 01, then 20, 11, 02, then 30, 21, 12, 03, etc... YOu can see that the first number decreases by 1 and the second number increases by 1. That goes until you hit n0...0n. That covers the first half of the square...

```
// Assume $n is the width/height of the square
for($m=0; $m<=$n; $m++)
{
    for($a=$n; $a>=0; $a--)
    {
        for($b=0; $b<=$n; $b++)
        {
            //Do whatever you want with $array[$a][$n]...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the second half of the square hits 41, 32, 23, 14 on the first stripe. It hits 42, 33, 24 on the second stripe. It hits 43, 34, and finally 44. You can see they both step up until they hit $n

```
for($m=1; $m<=$n; $m++)
{
    for($b=$m; $b<=$n; $b++) // Put B on the outside because it is the limitation
    {
        for($a=4; $b<=$n; $a--)
        {
            //Do what you want with $a and $b
        }
    }
}
```

Now... can this be deciphered easily? Yes. You are just scrambling up the letters. No matter how you scramble it, it is deciphered easily. You need to substitute the letters with a replacement set that changes. Optimally, you want a completely new replacement set per letter you replace - which is difficult to use. So, most ciphers use a set of replacement sets, say 32 sets of replacement letters or symbols, that cycle through as randomly as possible.

Comment: Haha I do know how to use loops, getting the spiral to wrap correctly was a mess of nested loops. Anyways I thought there might be some other simpler methods, but you really made it very clear to me what to do. It just wouldn't come to me :)Thanks!

Also, I'm guessing even character substitution doesn't help that much against computing power. If I want to make it at least non-trivially secure, would I have to integrate some sort of seed or public/private key mechanism? What would you suggest?